# Finding coeffiicients

Tags: combinatorics

Given series expansion: $z^2/(1+z)^8$
Find coefficient of $z^{12}$.

I know we can use geometric series to up solve $z^2/(1+z)^8$, by applying the series to $(1+z)^{-8}$. I don't know how to solve this though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried repeated diffentiation on 
$${1\over 1 + z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^n, \qquad |z| < 1?$$

Comment: While this suggestion sounds awful, if you carefully look at the patterns from differentiating $(1+z)^{-1}$ and $z^{n}$, you will find that you can produce the general term for your power series without vast amounts of effort.  You will have an alternating series with binomial coefficients that you can actually use a calculator on (whereas even WolframAlpha doesn't like $\left(\begin{array}{cc}-8\\10\end{array}\right)$  -- you can do that on a calculator, but you have to punch all the numbers for the product in yourself)...

Comment: A small amount of exploration will cause a pattern to jump right out at you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $[z^k]$ operator for "coefficient of $z^k$":
$$
[z^{12}] \frac{z^2}{(1 + z)^8}
  = [z^{10}] (1 + z)^{-8}
  = \binom{-8}{10}
$$
Just need that one now...

Comment: "Just need that one now..." Do you mean to evaluate -8 choose 10?

Comment: @SolBethanyReaves, yep.

Comment: @SolBethanyReaves, hint: $\displaystyle \binom{-n}{k} = \frac{- n (- n - 1) \ldots (- n - k + 1)}{k!} = \frac{(-1)^k n (n + 1) \ldots (n + k - 1)}{k!} =  \frac{(n + k - 1)!}{k! (n - 1)!} = \binom{n + k - 1}{k}$.